# How to link Question node to current page?

Tags: 7

I would like users to be able to ask questions related to current page without going to another page as it works now in the [Relevant Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/relevant_answers) module. There is a related issue: http://drupal.org/node/1826492

I can create a custom block with form in it, and create new `Question` node on submit.

How can I link that new node to current page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom block return your form like this.

```
global $user;
// You may need to get your path a different way here?
$original_path = implode('/', args());
// Just set the GET path to the path ^ from there.  The form_alter()
// will pick it up automatically for you on line 86 in relevant_answers.module.
$_GET['path'] = relevant_answers_compress_string($original_path);

$node = (object) array('type' => 'question', 'uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
$form = render(drupal_get_form('question_node_form', $node));

// Return your rendered form.
// You may need to do some stuff with redirecting if its not going to the right page after you submit.
return $form;
```

This is completely untested but should get you down the right path to solving your issue.

Comment: field_question_path path field can be added to a form if it is build from scratch: `$form['field_question_path'][$langcode][0]['value']['#value'] = $original_path`. Corresponding field will need to be updated on the node.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your Question-content type as a field called "node_reference_field" with the [EntityReference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.

Once that's done, you just need to make sure the nid of the current node is stored in this field. Since you're using a custom block with a generated form, it won't be that hard.
I suggest you try something like:

```
$node = node_load ($form_state['nid']);
$form['node_reference_field']['value'] = $node->nid;
```

I'm not sure about the coding, but with the EntityReference module, you aren't far from a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that this is how the "Relevant Answers" works?

Comment: I don't see why not. You can link as many nodes as you like with the reference

Comment: Ok, I see that this is a possible way to do this without "Relevant Answers", but I want a way to do this with "Relevant Answers".

Answer (score 2):

If I have correctly understood, you want to insert a block inside a node visualization. If so, I would suggest using the **context** module, you just have to insert the condition (usually the path of the content such as node/*) and set the reaction to block. You could then select you block and put it in one of the regions defined in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

The [Relevant Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/relevant_answers) module is one of the (separated) add-on modules for the 7.x-3.x version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module.

In the most recent 7.x-4.x version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module, this module has been obsoleted and replaced by the **Answers Best Answer** sub-module, which allows for marking any of the answers to a specific question as the best (accepted) answer (to display the blue checkmarks to the left of each answer, and which is replaced by a green checkmark when an answer is marked as the best answer).

With that, out-of-the-Anwers-box, you can now post a (new) answer right below a question, using a form that is similar to creating a new node.

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of this module.